# Spouse Pre-Tax HSA Contribution

Tags: united-states, hsa, contribution

My wife and I each have (unrelated) individual insurance through our respective employers, one Blue Cross/Blue Shield, the other Aetna.

Because I already have a HDHP with an HSA, she is barred from getting an FSA with her plan.

I know that since we are married, we can spend from my HSA for her medical expenses, and that she is also allowed to make contributions to my HSA "on my behalf".

However, is she able to contribute pre-tax to my HSA assuming her payroll can set up a pre-tax withdrawal?  Or is she limited to making post-tax contributions, and if so, is it still worth it?